# Regex to convert camel case to normal sentence while changing some to uppercase

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I am trying to convert to camel case words to a normal sentence text .

For Example :

```
productId to Product Id
productSize to Product Size
snapshotId to Snapshot Id
```

The problem is the field containing Id , I would want to convert them to "ID"

```
productId : Product ID
snapshotId: Snapshot ID
```

I have tried the following regex:

```
(str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1)).split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ")
```

How can I handle the Id case here?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Just `.map()` the elements before `.join()`ing them back together and replace `"Id"` with `"ID"`

Comment: Slap a `.replace(/\bId\b/, 'ID')` at the end of what you already got there?

Comment: ^ With the `g` flag if `Id` can occur more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split and map over the parts checking for Id.

```
str = str.split(/(?=[A-Z])/)
        .map(s => s === "Id" ? "ID" : s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1)).join(" ");
```

```js
[
  "productId",
  "productSize",
  "snapshotId"
].forEach(str => {
  str = str.split(/(?=[A-Z])/)
    .map(s => s === "Id" ? "ID" : s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1)).join(" ");
  console.log(str);
});
```

Comment: "Product ID" should be the output of "productId"